# How to repeat a choice using random

Tags: python, random, turtle-graphics

So I am trying to make a tic tac toe game where you can play against the computer. Because I do not know how to use AI for the computer so it can make a decision, I chose to have it use a random choice. Because it needs to make multiple choices for multiple turns, I want to figure out how to have the 'choice' variable loop, so it makes a different random choice each time the game loops. Here is the code.

```
import turtle
import random

# Define the screen
screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.setup(width=300, height=300)

# Define the turtle
t = turtle.Turtle()
t.speed(0)

error = "Move already made, you lost a turn"

moves = ["top left", "top mid", "top right", "mid left", "mid mid", "mid right", "bot left", "bot mid", "bot right"]
def top_left():
  t.penup()
  t.goto(-100, 100)
  t.pendown()
  makex()

def top_mid():
  t.penup()
  t.goto(0, 100)
  t.pendown()
  makex()

def top_right():
  t.penup()
  t.goto(100, 100)
  t.pendown()
  makex()

def mid_left():
  t.penup()
  t.goto(-100, 0)
  t.pendown()
  makex()

def mid_mid():
  t.penup()
  t.goto(0, 0)
  t.pendown()
  makex()

def mid_right():
  t.penup()
  t.goto(100, 0)
  t.pendown()
  makex()

def bot_left():
  t.penup()
  t.goto(-100, -100)
  t.pendown()
  makex()

def bot_mid():
  t.penup()
  t.goto(0, -100)
  t.pendown()
  makex()

def bot_right():
  t.penup()
  t.goto(100, -100)
  t.pendown()
  makex()

def pc_top_left():
  t.penup()
  t.goto(-100, 100)
  t.pendown()
  makeo()

def pc_top_mid():
  t.penup()
  t.goto(0, 100)
  t.pendown()
  makeo()

def pc_top_right():
  t.penup()
  t.goto(100, 100)
  t.pendown()
  makeo()

def pc_mid_left():
  t.penup()
  t.goto(-100, 0)
  t.pendown()
  makeo()

def pc_mid_mid():
  t.penup()
  t.goto(0, 0)
  t.pendown()
  makeo()

def pc_mid_right():
  t.penup()
  t.goto(100, 0)
  t.pendown()
  makeo()

def pc_bot_left():
  t.penup()
  t.goto(-100, -100)
  t.pendown()
  makex()

def pc_bot_mid():
  t.penup()
  t.goto(0, -100)
  t.pendown()
  makex()

def pc_bot_right():
  t.penup()
  t.goto(100, -100)
  t.pendown()
  makex()

def makex():
  t.pendown()
  t.left(45)
  t.forward(30)
  t.right(180)
  t.pendown()
  t.forward(60)
  t.penup()
  t.right(180)
  t.forward(30)
  t.right(90)
  t.forward(30)
  t.right(180)
  t.pendown()
  t.forward(60)
  t.penup()
  t.setheading(0)

def makeo():
  t.penup()
  t.right(90)
  t.forward(30)
  t.left(90)
  t.pendown()
  t.circle(30)
  t.penup()
  t.setheading(0)

def user(x, y):
  print(x, y)
  # Top row
  if y <= 150 and y >= 50:
    # Top left
    if x >= -150 and x <= -50:
      if "top left" in moves:
        print('top left')
        top_left()
        moves.remove("top left")
      else:
        print(error)
    # Top Mid
    elif x >= -50 and x <= 50:
      if "top mid" in moves:
        print('top mid')
        top_mid()
        moves.remove("top mid")
      else:
        print(error)
    # Top Right
    elif x >= 50 and x <= 150:
      if "top right" in moves:
        print('top right')
        top_right()
        moves.remove('top right')
      else:
        print(error)
  # Mid row
  elif y <= 50 and y >= -50:
    # Mid left
    if x >= -150 and x <= -50:
      if "mid left" in moves:
        print('mid left')
        mid_left()
        moves.remove('mid left')
      else:
        print(error)
    # Mid Mid
    elif x >= -50 and x <= 50:
      if 'mid mid' in moves:
        print('mid mid')
        mid_mid()
        moves.remove('mid mid')
      else:
        print(error)
    # Mid Right
    elif x >= 50 and x <= 150:
      if 'mid right' in moves:
        print('mid right')
        mid_right()
        moves.remove('mid right')
      else:
        print(error)
  # Bot row
  elif y <= -50 and y >= -150:
    # Bot left
    if x >= -150 and x <= -50:
      if 'bot left' in moves:
        print('bot left')
        bot_left()
        moves.remove('bot left')
      else:
        print(error)
    # Bot Mid
    elif x >= -50 and x <= 50:
      if 'bot mid' in moves:
        print('bot mid')
        bot_mid()
        moves.remove('bot mid')
      else:
        print(error)
    # Bot Right
    elif x >= 50 and x <= 150:
      if 'bot right' in moves:
        print('bot right')
        bot_right()
        moves.remove('bot right')
      else:
        print(error)
  print(moves)

def computer(choice):
  if choice == 'top left':
    pc_top_left()
    moves.remove('top left')

  elif choice == 'top mid':
    pc_top_mid()
    moves.remove('top mid')

  elif choice == 'top right':
    pc_top_right()
    moves.remove('top right')

  elif choice == 'mid left':
    pc_mid_left()
    moves.remove('mid left')

  elif choice == 'mid mid':
    pc_mid_mid()
    moves.remove('mid mid')

  elif choice == 'mid right':
    pc_mid_right()
    moves.remove('mid right')

  elif choice == 'bot left':
    pc_bot_left()
    moves.remove('bot left')

  elif choice == 'bot mid':
    pc_bot_mid()
    moves.remove('bot mid')

  elif choice == 'bot right':
    pc_bot_right()
    moves.remove('bot right')

def board_setup():
  t.penup()
  t.goto(-150, 50)
  t.pendown()
  t.forward(300)
  t.penup()
  t.goto(-150, -50)
  t.pendown()
  t.forward(300)
  t.penup()
  t.left(90)
  t.goto(-50, -150)
  t.pendown()
  t.forward(300)
  t.penup()
  t.goto(50, -150)
  t.pendown()
  t.forward(300)
  t.setheading(0)

# Game loop
board_setup()
screen.listen()
screen.onscreenclick(user)
choice = random.choice(moves)
computer(choice)
screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the issue is, can you clarify things?

Answer (score 0):

If you want different values each time you run, put "random.seed()" at the top of your program.  See random module docs for an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue seems to be you don't know how to make the user and the computer alternate turns.  One solution is to check in the user move event handler whether the user made a valid move, and if so, and there are moves left, tell the computer to make a move.  I've used that approach below and simplified your code in the process:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import choice

moves = [ \
    'top left', 'top mid', 'top right', \
    'mid left', 'mid mid', 'mid right', \
    'bot left', 'bot mid', 'bot right', \
]

def makex(x, y):
    t.goto(x, y)

    t.pendown()
    t.left(45)
    t.forward(30)
    t.right(180)
    t.pendown()
    t.forward(60)

    t.penup()
    t.right(180)
    t.forward(30)
    t.right(90)
    t.forward(30)
    t.right(180)

    t.pendown()
    t.forward(60)

    t.penup()
    t.setheading(0)

def makeo(x, y):
    t.goto(x, y)

    t.right(90)
    t.forward(30)
    t.left(90)

    t.pendown()
    t.circle(30)

    t.penup()
    t.setheading(0)

def user(x, y):
    valid_move = False

    if moves:
        # Top row
        if 50 < y < 150:
            # Top left
            if -150 < x < -50:
                if 'top left' in moves:
                    makex(-100, 100)
                    moves.remove('top left')
                    valid_move = True
            # Top Mid
            elif -50 < x < 50:
                if 'top mid' in moves:
                    makex(0, 100)
                    moves.remove('top mid')
                    valid_move = True
            # Top Right
            elif 50 < x < 150:
                if 'top right' in moves:
                    makex(100, 100)
                    moves.remove('top right')
                    valid_move = True
        # Mid row
        elif -50 < y < 50:
            # Mid left
            if -150 < x < -50:
                if 'mid left' in moves:
                    makex(-100, 0)
                    moves.remove('mid left')
                    valid_move = True
            # Mid Mid
            elif -50 < x < 50:
                if 'mid mid' in moves:
                    makex(0, 0)
                    moves.remove('mid mid')
                    valid_move = True
            # Mid Right
            elif 50 < x < 150:
                if 'mid right' in moves:
                    makex(100, 0)
                    moves.remove('mid right')
                    valid_move = True
        # Bot row
        elif -150 < y < -50:
            # Bot left
            if -150 < x < -50:
                if 'bot left' in moves:
                    makex(-100, -100)
                    moves.remove('bot left')
                    valid_move = True
            # Bot Mid
            elif -50 < x < 50:
                if 'bot mid' in moves:
                    makex(0, -100)
                    moves.remove('bot mid')
                    valid_move = True
            # Bot Right
            elif 50 < x < 150:
                if 'bot right' in moves:
                    makex(100, -100)
                    moves.remove('bot right')
                    valid_move = True

    if valid_move and moves:
        computer(choice(moves))

def computer(choice):
    screen.onscreenclick(None)  # disable user during computer move

    if choice == 'top left':
        makeo(-100, 100)
        moves.remove('top left')
    elif choice == 'top mid':
        makeo(0, 100)
        moves.remove('top mid')
    elif choice == 'top right':
        makeo(100, 100)
        moves.remove('top right')
    elif choice == 'mid left':
        makeo(-100, 0)
        moves.remove('mid left')
    elif choice == 'mid mid':
        makeo(0, 0)
        moves.remove('mid mid')
    elif choice == 'mid right':
        makeo(100, 0)
        moves.remove('mid right')
    elif choice == 'bot left':
        makeo(-100, -100)
        moves.remove('bot left')
    elif choice == 'bot mid':
        makeo(0, -100)
        moves.remove('bot mid')
    elif choice == 'bot right':
        makeo(100, -100)
        moves.remove('bot right')

    if moves:  # reenable user if it's possible to move
        screen.onscreenclick(user)

def board_setup():
    t.penup()
    t.goto(-150, 50)
    t.pendown()
    t.forward(300)
    t.penup()
    t.goto(-150, -50)
    t.pendown()
    t.forward(300)

    t.left(90)

    t.penup()
    t.goto(-50, -150)
    t.pendown()
    t.forward(300)
    t.penup()
    t.goto(50, -150)
    t.pendown()
    t.forward(300)

    t.penup()
    t.setheading(0)

screen = Screen()

# Define the turtle
t = Turtle()
t.hideturtle()
t.speed('fastest')

board_setup()

computer(choice(moves))

screen.mainloop()
```

There's more code simplification that could be done, but it's not worth it at this point.  Your next hurdle is to add scoring logic to determine if either player has won or if they've reached a draw.